# Qbs 1.10 module cpp not be loaded

Tags: qt, qt-creator, stm32, qbs

After upgrading QtCreator from 4.4.1 to version 4.5.0 and then updating Qbs from 1.9.0 to version 1.10.0, an error appeared: "... warning: Module cpp could not be loaded." "Product 'ProductName' had errors and was disabled."
It was possible to find the following bugreport [QBS-709](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-709?jql=project%20%3D%20QBS).

However, the link in the last post is not working. Please help me find a solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update && Solution:** Founded newest bugreport: [QBS-1263](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-1263). Next, go to [code review](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/213981/).

For solution of problem need to change share/qbs/modules/cpp/GenericGCC.qbs file

Need to change this lines:

```
CppModule { 
    condition: false
```

to the next:

```
CppModule { 
    condition: qbs.toolchain && qbs.toolchain.contains("gcc")   
    priority: -100
```

Comment: Should be fixed in 1.10.1